# Why is my Python proxy not accepting connections?

Tags: python, tcp, proxy

I am trying to develop a TCP proxy library using Python 3. I have based my code on Python 2 example code, written by LiveOverflow. His original code is found in [his video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iApNzWZG-10). My proxy library is intended to work like this: there is a proxy object containing a server-side object and a client-side object. The client-side object mimics a server, while the server-side object mimics a client. The two pass data to each other through the parent proxy object. To initiate the proxy, the script using the library instantiates the proxy with the port the client side is going to host on and the ip address and port the server side is going to connect to. Here is the code:

TCP.py:

```py
from threading import Thread
import socket as sock

class proxy():
    def __init__(self, cSidePort, sSideIP, sSidePort, connections = 1, packetSize = 4096):
        self.connections = connections
        self.cSide = clientSide(self, cSidePort)
        print('proxy: initialized cSide')
        self.sSide = serverSide(self, sSideIP, sSidePort)
        print('proxy: initialized sSide')
        
        self.cSide.start()
        print('proxy: started cSide')
        self.sSide.start()
        print('proxy: started cSide')

class clientSide(Thread):
    def __init__(self, parentProxy, port):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        print('clientSide: Thread.__init__ called')
        self.parentProxy = parentProxy
        self.port = port
        self.socket = sock.socket(sock.AF_INET, sock.SOCK_STREAM)
        print('clientSide: socket created')
        self.socket.bind(('', self.port))
        print('clientSide: socket bound')
        print('clientSide: Ip address of the proxy is: {}'.format(sock.gethostbyname(sock.gethostname())))
        self.socket.listen(self.parentProxy.connections)
        print('clientSide: socket listening')
        self.conn, self.connAddr = self.socket.accept()
        print('clientSide: socket has connection')

    def run(self):
        print('clientSide: run called')
        while(True):
            data = self.conn.recv(self.parentProxy.packetSize)
            if data:
                self.parentProxy.sSide.sendall(data)

    def sendall(self, data):
        print('clientSide: sendall called')
        self.conn.sendall(data)

class serverSide(Thread):
    def __init__(self, parentProxy, port, serverIP, serverPort):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.parentProxy = parentProxy
        self.port = port
        self.serverIP = serverIP
        self.serverPort = serverPort
        self.socket = sock.socket(sock.AF_INET, sock.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind(('', self.port))
        self.socket.connect((self.serverIP, self.serverPort))

    def run(self):
        while(True):
            data = self.socket.recv(4096)
            if data:
                self.parentProxy.sSide.sendall(data)

    def sendall(self, data):
        self.socket.sendall(data)
```

exampleProxy.py:

```py
import TCP
import socket as sock

tcpProxy = TCP.proxy(443, sock.gethostbyname('example.com'), 443)
```

Then I call exampleProxy.py from Powershell:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

Loading profile for aweso...
Profile loaded.
PS [*****] C:\Users\*****\Documents\Source\Python\proxy> python exampleProxy.py
clientSide: Thread.__init__ called
clientSide: socket created
clientSide: socket bound
clientSide: Ip address of the proxy is: 192.168.**.*
clientSide: socket listening
```

As the the debugging shows, the proxy script lags out at `self.socket.accept()` in the `clientSide` class. When I open Microsoft Edge on my iPhone and type the IP address printed by the proxy, the browser times out trying to connect to that page. Then I check the IP address of the proxy in the Windows WiFi properties, which is different from the one the proxy reported. I type that IP into the browser on my phone and nothing happens. I have also tried connecting to the proxy via my android tablet, which yielded the same results. I know the computer running the proxy can host, as I have done socket communication between it and my laptop.

Now the question is this: Why is the proxy not actually taking connections?

**Edit for additional information:**

I have created a basic web hosting script to show that the computer is capable of hosting a socket connection:

main.py:

```py
import socket

def web_page():
    with open('index.html', 'rb') as indexFile:
        html = indexFile.read()
    return html

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 80))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('Got a connection from {}\n\n'.format(addr))
    request = conn.recv(1024)
    print('Request: {}'.format(request))
    response = web_page()
    conn.send(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n')
    conn.send(b'Content-Type: text/html\n')
    conn.send(b'Connection: close\n\n')
    conn.sendall(response)
    conn.close()
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    div {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 5em auto;
        padding: 2em;
        background-color: #fdfdff;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
    }
    a:link, a:visited {
        color: #38488f;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        div {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: auto;
        }
    }
    </style>    
</head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>This is a test.</h1>
            <p>If you are reading this, it works!</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I ran main.py and called the computer's IP address in my phone's browser. This gave me the expected webpage. I then tried main.py again using port 443. This caused the no connection issue. I am going to try changing ports in the proxy example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. Browsers use a random port to send http/https requests. As I understand, this can be circumvented by adding a colon and the desired port number to the end of the url.